# localStorage save HTML Clone

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to use the localStorage to save an Object which contains HTML-Clones.

```
var myObject["test"] = document.getElementByID("someElement").cloneNode(true);
myObject["test2"] = document.getElementByID("someOtherElement").cloneNode(true);
localStorage.saveObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

But the Object saveObject still equals {}. It seems, that stringify can't stringify an HTML Node and if, in any way, I happen to solve the problem to save it, is it possible to parse this Object back to an HTML node?

Someone knows a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node references will be removed from the stringified object because JSON, by definition, cannot contain functions or node references - only primitives or sub-arrays/objects. In other words, there's no way you can keep references to nodes in your local storage. You would instead need to log references to them by ID, class or some other means.

[**EDIT**, in response to OP's comment]

JSON and JS objects are not the same thing. The former is derived from the latter, but they are not the same. JSON is a storage means, and so cannot contain references to anything dynamic. HTML elements do not exist permanently; they exist as runtime (DOM) concepts that disappear once the page is left. Thus, they cannot be stored in any meaningful way.

JSON is therefore able to store only primitive data - strings, numbers and booleans - along with structures that allow it to nest - arrays and sub-JSON definitions.

So what happens when you run `stringify` on your object is the unsuitable parts are stripped out. In your case, that's both properties. So instead, you need to store references to the elements in a more permanent, revisitable format - by ID or class, or some other reminder mechanism.

```
var obj = {el1: '#some_element', el2: '.some_other_element'};
localStorage.saveObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

There I save my two elements as references to their IDs (first) and class (second).

Then, when you come to reload your local storage, you look up the elements based on those factors, by feeding them, for example, to a jQuery selector.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I don't really understand it :(

Comment: Well this seems to be a quite nice way but:

The HTML-Nodes I want to store aren't actually on the same Page, I want to use them. So there is a subpage www.mypage.com/subpage, where a lot of html-nodes are with the class "some_other_element" and I want to pick some of them (via Button) and save their HTML-Code to show the same Code on the main Page www.mypage.com. And if I close the Website and reload it it should search in the localStorage for stored HTML Elements and reload them on the main Page.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to:

1. Get the outerHTML of the node you want to clone
2. Store the outerHTML (a string) in local storage.
3. On load create a new element, append it to the document.
4. Assign the outerHTML saved in your localstorage to the new element.

Quick example:

```
window.saveArray = new Array();
var clone = document.getElementByID("someElement").cloneNode(true);
saveArray.push(clone.outerHTML);

function save(){
    localStorage["elements"] = JSON.stringify(saveArray);
}
function load(){
    var tempsave = JSON.parse(localStorage["elements"]);

    for (var i = 0; i < tempsave.length; i++){      
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        document.getElementById('element-container').appendChild(element); 
        element.outerHTML = tempsave[i];    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save an HTML node as string you can use XMLSerializer.

```
var node = document.getElementByID("elementID");
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var htmlStr = serializer.serializeToString(node);
localStorage.setItem("saved", htmlStr);
```

Now you can set it as innerHTML of a node.

```
document.getElementById("elementContainerID").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("saved");
```

Notice! If you are copying input elements that have been given new values, they will not be saved. As the node will be copied with the value attribute `inputElement.getAttribute("value")` and not with the new given one `inputElement.value`. To work around this, you may copy all input values to the value attribute before you serializer the node.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((el) => el.setAttribute("value", el.value));
```